# auto build error while shifting from vs2005 to 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, msbuild

Recently we migrated our project from VS205 to VS2010. Post migration we are observing the problem with automated build. Please, see below the details.

Build machine is set up with CruiseControl and a NAnt script for automated builds with devenv.

Building with VS2010 causes a number of (most) projects to start, but not finish (the only message for each project is “Rebuild All started…”). This is the pattern we have observed:

```
-------Rebuild All started: Project: Scheduler, Configuration: BuildTWinWithPortalSvc x86 ------
------ Rebuild All started: Project: CSerial, Configuration: BuildTWinWithPortalSvc Win32 ------
------ Rebuild All started: Project: sockeeg, Configuration: BuildTWinWithPortalSvc Win32 ------
```

TwinPortalSetup.vd  project gives the message:

> An error occurred while validating.  HRESULT=’80004005’

Building (on the same machine) with the command line or from the IDE results in no errors.

This script is almost identical to the one that builds the VS2005 solution, which works fine.

Comment: It always fascinates me the way people post questions. We showed you a preview of that. Did you think it looked good? Did you think it was readable? Did you think people would take the time to answer it?

Comment: hi Cody... first of all thank you for editing the question and making it understandable. actually this is not my question this problem is being faced by my buddy he forwarded this to me even m not familiar with this thingy i just posted so that good experienced coders like you can help in solving this problem ..

Comment: Not sure, I've never seen this problem anymore. From what I find online, the HRESULT value 80004005 is a CRC/hash check error. Looks like something in your project file is corrupted. Perhaps you can try recreating a fresh new project file, then just adding your existing code files to it? Most likely, something went wrong during the conversion process.